# What is maximum value of int or long in Google App Engine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What is maximum value for IntegerProperty, LongProperty in Google App Engine Python?

Answer (score 5):

There is no `LongProperty` on Google App Engine, but only [`IntegerProperty`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties?hl=es#types) and as already pointed it's a 64-bit signed integer.

This number has a minimum `−9,223,372,036,854,775,808` and maximum `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

Comment: this is the same for java ?

Answer (score 4):

IntegerProperty is an int or a long:

int or long
An integer value, up to 64 bits.

Python int values are converted to Python long values prior to storage. A value stored as an int will be returned as a long.

If a long larger than 64 bits is assigned, only the least significant 64 bits are stored.

And for added clarity, you can use sys.maxint to find the actual value (run this in a shell and "import sys" first)

Comment: I think sys.maxint != datastore maximum int so I will not use it. Ineed about 46 bits so its perfect type.